# Why can't install the pypi package with virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, python-venv

The pypi package can be installed into  user directory:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.11.2
echo $USER
debian
```

Start to install

```
pip install vnstock  --break-system-packages
```

Check the installed location:

```
pip show vnstock
Name: vnstock
Version: 0.1.6
Summary: Vietnam Stock Market Data
Home-page: https://github.com/thinh-vu/vnstock
Author: Thinh Vu
Author-email: mrthinh@live.com
License: 
Location: /home/debian/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Try to make a new installation with virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv  project
cd  project
debian@debian:~/project$ source  bin/activate
(project) debian@debian:~/project$ pip install vnstock --break-system-packages
bash: /home/debian/project/bin/pip: cannot execute: required file not found
(project) debian@debian:~/project$
```

Why can't install the pypi package with virtual environment?
No use to install without any argument.

```
pip install vnstock 
bash: /home/debian/project/bin/pip: cannot execute: required file not found
```

Please install debian12 first and try to install pypi package with virtual environment,then post your answer.

Comment: Just install without `--break-system-packages` in the virtual environment.

Comment: Talk is cheap,try in your local pc please,you would get the same output as mine.

Comment: Let me try try~

Comment: Both MacOS and Ubuntu20 worked. But I don't know how to install debian12.

Comment: Never happened to me in my older debian11+python3.9.

Comment: Download ventoy and debian 12 iso image ,set usb boot in your bios,then reboot ,it will start a new installation.

Comment: Does `python -m pip` work?